# Rails Paperclip Displaying Image Title, Not Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I just installed Paperclip on my rails app and have gotten it to upload an image, but it still displays just the image name and a broken image icon instead of displaying the actual URL.

My `user.rb` model shows:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
  :default_url => "/avatars/default_:style_avatar.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

My `users_controller.rb` shows:

```
def create
  @user = User.create( user_params )
  ...
end

...

  private

 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
 end
```

And my form/display looks like this (the if/else is #ed out for troubleshooting purposes):

```
<%# if current_user.avatar != nil %>
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
<%# else %>
     <p>Looks a little impersonal...<br>Wanna upload a profile picture:</p>
     <%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
        <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
        <%= form.submit "Upload Picture", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
<%# end %>
```

I have checked in my `schema.rb` file and the migration to add `:avatar` to the user table was successful:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "first_name"
   t.string   "last_name"
   t.string   "email"
   t.string   "password_digest"
   t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
   t.integer  "role"
   t.string   "slug"
   t.string   "avatar_file_name"
   t.string   "avatar_content_type"
   t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
   t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["slug"], name: "index_users_on_slug", unique: true
```

However, I do not see anywhere the uploaded images are being saved.  I also don't see anything paperclip related in my `initializers` folder, so maybe it has something to do with installation of the gem?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are uploading correctly they must be copying inside your public directory, check it.

Another thing you can try is, create a new model lets say `photos`. And their association is like `user, has_many :photos` and attach your avatar in photo model.

Comment: That's the interesting part. There aren't any saved photos (other than my error messages) in the public directory.